# How to automatically put rel="nofollow" for all the external links in SummerNote editor?

Tags: summernote, rel, nofollow

I just recently tried to implement the SummerNote editor in my project but then I realized that all the external links don't have the rel="nofollow" attribute.

How can I include this attribute automatically?

Thanks for the help.
minedbp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is to:
1) Download the CDN Summernote JavaScript file and store within your application folders which is to be bound to your code as path instead of https url.

2) Open, Clean and Modify the code. Search for the line where the `<a>` element is being created and add the property you want.

Here are points where the HTML Anchor element is being created:

a)

```
 var anchors = [];
                if (isTextChanged) {
                    rng = rng.deleteContents();
                    var anchor = rng.insertNode($$1('<A>' + linkText + '</A>')[0]);
                    anchors.push(anchor);
                }
```

b)

```
AutoLink.prototype.replace = function () {
            if (!this.lastWordRange) {
                return;
            }
            var keyword = this.lastWordRange.toString();
            var match = keyword.match(linkPattern);
            if (match && (match[1] || match[2])) {
                var link = match[1] ? keyword : defaultScheme + keyword;
                var node = $$1('<a />').html(keyword).attr('href', link)[0];
                this.lastWordRange.insertNode(node);
                this.lastWordRange = null;
                this.context.invoke('editor.focus');
            }
        };
```

c)

```
 var anchors = [];
                if (isTextChanged) {
                    rng = rng.deleteContents();
                    var anchor = rng.insertNode($$1('<A>' + linkText + '</A>')[0]);
                    anchors.push(anchor);
                }
```

Simply search for **`<a`** on the document to see these methods. Edit as appropriately and you're good to go.